Schedule monotony constraints
Suppose I have a model for creating a nurse's duty roster. The model has the indices $i$ for the person, $t$ for the day and $s$ for the shift. I have the binary variable $x_{its}$ which indicates whether a person is working or not. Now I want to "capture" the monotony of working hours in a new variable. For example, if a nurse works the same shift for 14 days, with or without break days, then this should be stored in a new binary variable. How could I do this?

Is a shift a sequence of hours, or days?

A sequence of hours, a day has three shifts

Do you mean exactly 14 days or at least 14 days?

@RobPratt for exactly 14 days, but I want to define this monotony variable $y_{id}$ for every $i$ and day $t$, so f.e on day 15, the shifts were the same for person $i$, which yield $y_{i15}=1$, but now on day 15 the shift changes, which means $y_{i16}=0$, as the 14 days prior to day 16 were not always the same. So I want to show each day for each person whether the last 14 days have been monotonous.

Define a new binary variable $y_{its}$ that takes value $1$ if nurse $i$ works the same shift $s$ for $n$ consecutive days (exactly), starting on day $t$.
You want to enforce:
$$
\neg x_{i,t-1,s} \wedge \left(\bigwedge_{j=t}^{t+n-1} x_{ijs}\right) \wedge \neg x_{i,t+n,s}  \implies y_{its}\quad \forall i,s,t
$$
Or equivalently via CNF:
\begin{align}
&\neg \left(\neg x_{i,t-1,s} \wedge \left(\bigwedge_{j=t}^{t+n-1} x_{ijs}\right) \wedge \neg x_{i,t+n,s}\right)  \vee y_{its}\quad &\forall i,s,t  \\
&  x_{i,t-1,s} \vee \left(\bigvee_{j=t}^{t+n-1} \neg x_{ijs}\right) \vee x_{i,t+n,s} \vee y_{its}\quad &\forall i,s,t  \\
&x_{i,t-1,s} + \sum_{j=t}^{t+n-1} (1- x_{ijs}) + x_{i,t+n,s} + y_{its} \ge 1\quad &\forall i,s,t  \\
& \sum_{j=t}^{t+n-1}  x_{ijs} \le x_{i,t-1,s} + x_{i,t+n,s} + y_{its} + (n-1) \quad &\forall i,s,t 
\end{align}
If you need to enforce the converse:
$$
 y_{its} \implies \neg x_{i,t-1,s} \wedge \left(\bigwedge_{j=t}^{t+n-1} x_{ijs}\right) \wedge \neg x_{i,t+n,s}  \quad \forall i,s,t
$$
The same method yields:
\begin{align}
y_{its} + x_{i,t-1,s} &\le 1 &\forall i,s,t\\
y_{its} + x_{i,t+n,s} &\le 1  &\forall i,s,t\\
y_{its} &\le x_{ijs}  &\forall i,s,t, j\in\{t,\cdots,t+n-1\}\\
\end{align}

Thank you very much. Can I also definie $y_{is}$ as $y_{it}$, indicating that the monotony occurs in day $t$? And for which indices is the upper constraint defined? I guess it is not $\forall t\in T$?

you could use $y_{is}^t$ to indicate that the monotony occurs for nurse $i$ with shift $s$ on days $t,...,t+n-1$.

Indeed, the upper constraint is defined for $t=1,\cdots,|T|-n+1$. You need to be careful at the borders. For example, for $t=1$, replace $x_{i,0,s}$ by $0$. And same for $t=|T|-n+1$: replace $x_{i,|T|+1,s}$ by $0$.

Thanks. Can I also definie $z_{it}=\sum_{s\in S} y_{is}^t$, would this not add up? And can I also define the constraints for the last $n$ days and not to following one?

In the first of the three inequality constraints, should $t$ be $t-1$? Also, since the inequalities test a streak of exactly $n$ days with the same shift starting on day $t$, shouldn't $y$ have a subscript $t$?

@prubin thank you for your comments, I agree and have edited accordingly.

@Kuifje Thanks. Does my proposed summation work?

@manofthousandnames yes you could define suche a summation, but it is hard to say that it will "work"; it depends on what you want to do with this sum.
