Binary Block Variables for Consecutive Shifts in Scheduling
I just finished reading into the topic of staff scheduling and I was wondering if the following idea/concept was somehow already discussed, maybe under another name, with me not being able to find it.
I was thinking about the idea of blocks. For instance, I have the typical shift assignment variable $(x_{itj} \in \mathbb{B})$, with $i$ being the index for the worker, $t$ for the days, and $j$ for the shifts.
Now assuming I have on five consecutive days the same shift type, I then want to encode a new binary block variable $z^{block}_{itj}$ which equals 1 if there was the same shift assignment five consecutive days. So for instance, the set of shifts is defined as $s\in S = \{1,2,3\}$, and we have the following shift assignments from day $1$ to $7$:
$$ \{OFF-1-1-1-1-1-2 \},$$ then only $z^{block}_{i61}=1$ holds.
Subsequently, this block variable is then used to compute the number over all these blocks for each worker over the whole planning horizon, which is then properly weighted in the objective function (negative weight, as it is preferred). Is there already a similar concept or is this rather new?

Just for clarification, 1) should off be on the shift list? (e.g. $ { off, 1, 2, 3 }$). 2) What exactly you mean by defining a new variable, actually the extra four-times combinations on the solver, to capture the consecutive shift patterns? 3) What does $6$ mean in $z^{block}_{i61}$?

@A.Omidi  Regarding 1), well off means no shift assignment on the given day. 2) I don't quite understand your point. 3) day 6 shift 1

https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/12028/schedule-monotony-constraints

@RobPratt Thank you. Do you know if this is a concept used before?
